# Integrating activeCollab with my Django project

Tags: python, django, api

I have tried looking all over the net for some help, and couldn't find anything.  I'm posting here because I am out of all other ideas.  I want to integrate [activeCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/) with my django project but I am having trouble finding tutorials or instructions on how to use their API with django.  All of the aC documentation is for php, and I can't find any examples or tutorials on how to integrate it with django/python. Has anyone had experience with this sort of thing, or knows where to point me?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any tutorials on how to use activecollab with python & django.  However, using PyFacebook was a big help, for learning how to interact with API's.  Also, knowing PHP helped, as I took a look at some PHP tutorials on using API's as well.  Hope this helps with other people going through the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does "all over the net" include the [activeCollab marketplace forum](http://www.activecollab.com/forums/forum/25/)? Try "I will pay $300 for someone to convert the PHP API wrapper to Python" or something more specific describing exactly what you want to accomplish through Django.

If you haven't already purchased an activeCollab license, you might look at [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), the open source python equivalent.

P.S. I am currently available if you wish to hire me.